# Batch script store data within itself

Tags: file, batch-file, save, internal

I am making a memory game in batch for fun and came upon a problem.  I had a high score's file for player scores and no mater what file type i used it could be read and edited.

I am wondering if it is possible for a .bat file to store data within itself permanently, even after i close the program.  So when open it again the data will still be there.  Is this possible?

Thank-you in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /R /N "end_of_batch_label" "%~f0"' ) do set end_batch=%%D

echo -- HERE WE MAKE A NEW SELF CONTAINED RECORD --

echo echo data entry 4^>^>"%~f0"
echo(>>"%~f0"
echo data entry ^4>>"%~f0"

echo -- HERE STARTS PRINTING OF SELF CONTAINED DATA --
type "%~f0" | more +%end_batch%
exit /b 0


:end_of_batch_label

data entry 1
data entry 2


data entry 3
```

Of course it is.Try the code above.

Comment: Thank-you, but can you explain this.  I am relatively new to programming and well this is a little beyond me.

Comment: The data entries starts after `:end_of_batch_label`.With `findstr /R /N "end_of_batch_label" "%~f0"` we can find all lined that contains `end_of_batch_label` and putting this command in `FOR /F` we can extract the last line of these.With `more +number` we can print the content of the file after the pointed line.Hope this will help...

Comment: Is it possible to save a players score in in a batch game in the .bat file then call the data?  Also what does "%~f0" and more +%end_batch% do?

Comment: "%~f0" is a special parameter that will hold the path to batch file (unless shift command is used) .` +%end_batch% ` is a parameter passed to the `MORE` command (after the line where `end_of_batch_label` is found and the number is assigned to  end_batch).E.g `type some_file|more +5` will print all content of `some_file` after the 5th line.